# VirtualBox Vboxmanager not seeing VMs

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox, symbolic-link

I need to enable symlinks in my virtualbox shared file called sf_VMShare following this tutorial.

When I run the command:

```
 VBoxManage setextradata YOURVMNAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/YOURSHAREFOLDERNAME 1
```

I get the following error:

```
  C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage setextradata Ubuntu Home Disk      
  VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/sf_VMShare 1
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Ubuntu'
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001),     
  component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
  VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" 
  at line 797 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

So reading the error I figure ok I am mistyping the VM name so I make sure to add the extra space after the end and I still get the same error.

I am in the symlink group and am running the command as an administrator. Im out of ideas thanks all!

**EDIT:**

Per Bobs answer I ran the command "list vms"

```
 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe list vms
 "Ubuntu Home Disk " {5bc6053b-bc8b-42c7-9c58-24935d281a82}
```

So I took the listed UUID

```
 "5bc6053b-bc8b-42c7-9c58-24935d281a82"
```

Ran the command

```
 VBoxManage setextradata  5bc6053b-bc8b-42c7-9c58-24935d281a82 VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/sv_vmShare 1
```

and ran it was accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the UUID for the machine with this command:

> VBoxManage list vms

and use the UUID instead of the name in the command.

Comment: Ran the command editing the question to reflect

Answer (score 0):

To add a VM to the Virtual Media Manager...

vboxmanage disk {path/to/VM/VMname} --setlocation {/Path/to/VM/VMname}

i.e. vboxmanage disk /VM/SSHLinux/SSHLinux.vdi --setlocation /VM/SSHLinux/SSHlinux.vdi

than to register the VM...

vboxmanage registervm {Path/To/VM/VMname}

i.e. vboxmanage registervm /VM/SSHLinux/SSHLinux.vbox